# I am thinking about that if i connect the DC generator with transformer only, will the transformer works? If then why it isn't use in power plant?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current

the electricity produce by DC generator is sinusoidal. I think that it may works but the thing is why it isn't use in power plant as ac and DC current (produced by generator without smoothing) can be step-up or step-down

Comment: There's nothing about DC current or voltage that's sinusoidal. The "A" in AC refers to the alternating, sinusoidal nature of current/voltage, but that doesn't occur with DC power.

Comment: It is an abuse of the word "sinusoidal", but presumably this refers to a DC generator with a commutator so that the voltage comes out (hypothetically) like this:  https://dc.edu.au/wp-content/uploads/ac-vs-dc-generators.png   The original question remains interesting since the current still varies, though in a lesser way.

Comment: Transformers that work base on the varying flux linkage are only useful if the inputs are time-varying signals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a conceptual explanation. Let me know if you need the formulas as well.

The output of the transformer is related to the **change** in the magnetic field of the primary. You can write your approximately DC current as a constant one plus the changing one around the average. You are producing both with the generator, but the average is lost when you put it through the transformer. So your efficiency is low. Think what would happen if you have a constant 10A current, and a sinusoidal current on top of that with amplitude of 10A.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ideal elements, i.e., *ideal dc source* and *ideal lossless inductors*, then when you connect the source to the primary you will short circuit it irrespective of what the load on the secondary is; in practice that means that you will burn either the transformer or the source or both.

The reason why this does *not* happen when you drive the transformer with an *ideal* ac source (zero source impedance) is that the transformer represents a non-zero load to the source and not a short circuit. The actual input load depends on the ac frequency, on the transformer ratio and on the primary/secondary/mutual inductances and parasitic resistances, etc., and also on the load terminating the secondary; their combination is not zero at the input.

Comment: Can you explain further why short circuit happen when dc generator connect to transformer

Answer (score 0):

When a DC voltage is applied to the primary winding of a transformer, due to low resistance, the winding acts as a short circuit across the terminals of the DC source that lead to the flow of heavy current through the winding resulting in overheating of the winding.